# How to secure my python socket packets

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, security, server

I have TCP/IP Socket **client/server** program in python.I want to secure these packets.I want to know your opinion about this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the client and server doing? Can you not use use https as your interface between the client and server?

Comment: This is far too broad for a SO question. You should read (again?) [ask]...

Comment: One alternative is the [\[Python\]: *ssl* — TLS/SSL wrapper for socket objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) module that comes with _Python_ by default. It wraps the regular sockets, offering same interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to go would be to use OpenSSL to wrap your packets in SSL (`Secure Socket Layer`, it is the protocol used to secure the connection in HTTPS).

The pyOpenSSL repository has an [example project](https://github.com/msabramo/pyOpenSSL/tree/master/examples/simple) you can use to build your application.